# Turn box2d body invisible on mouse click or touch

Tags: java, android

[image]

As you can see in the picture I have a box2d world with some bodies. I have a inputproccessor set up as well but I can't seem to be able to make the boxes disappear when I click on them.

I basically want a way for my mouse clicks/touch to check if it intersects with the bodies/box. If it does I want that body to disappear. Could someone point me in the right direciton? I tried setting up a stage and making the bodies into buttons so that onClickListen would work but that turned out messy and wouldn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I managed to solve this on my own. This is the code I wrote in my inputproccessor class.
You need to declare hitBody at the top of class as a body btw which isn't shown below.

```
 Vector3 testPoint = new Vector3();
    QueryCallback callback = new QueryCallback() {

        @Override
        public boolean reportFixture(Fixture fixture) {
            if(fixture.testPoint(testPoint.x,testPoint.y)){
                hitBody = fixture.getBody();
                return false;
            }else{
                return true;
            }

        }
    };

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {

        GameRender.cam.unproject(testPoint.set(screenX,screenY,0));
        hitBody = null;
        GameWorld.physicsWorld.QueryAABB(callback, testPoint.x - 0.0001f,
                                        testPoint.y - 0.0001f,
                                        testPoint.x + 0.0001f,
                                        testPoint.y + 0.0001f);

        for(DynamicBox b:GameWorld.BoxList){
            if(hitBody == b.boxerino){
                System.out.println("click detected");
                b.shouldRemove = true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

There is a boolean which I turn to true if the body is clicked.(b.shouldRemove=true) After that I go to my update loop and remove the body and also the body factory class from the arrayList.

```
public void update(float delta){



        physicsWorld.step(delta, 2, 2);



        for(int i=0;i<BoxList.size();i++){
            DynamicBox b = BoxList.get(i);
            if(b.shouldRemove==true){
                physicsWorld.destroyBody(b.boxerino);
                BoxList.remove(i);
            }
        }
    }
```